# Find the relationship between input and number of times a loop executes.

Tags: algorithm, sequences

Given this code:

```
k = 1;
p = 0;
while (k < n){
  k *= 3;
  p++;
}
```

Define the number of times line 03 will execute in terms of n, where n is the input.  (Hint: Find out how p and k are related to n at the end of the loop in line 06.  Express p in therms of n and use that to answer this question.)

So far what I've done is figured out the number of times p and k execute related to these values of n:

- n = 1 -> k/p iterations = 1
- n = 3 -> k/p iterations = 3
- n = 10 -> k/p iterations = 3
- n = 30 -> k/p iterations = 4

I'm struggling to figure out how to define a relationship between n and the number of iterations for k/p.  If someone could please explain how to determine this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've approached this problem by trying out a couple of different examples and looking to see if you can spot a pattern. That's a reasonable approach to take, but it's a bit tricky to get working. Instead, you might want to look at the values that k takes on as the loop iterates and see if you can work from there.

Notice that k grows exponentially as a function of the number of loop iterations: it takes on the values 1, 3, 9, 27, 81, ... . Written differently, it takes on the values

> 3<sup>0</sup>, 3<sup>1</sup>, 3<sup>2</sup>, 3<sup>3</sup>, 3<sup>4</sup>, etc.

And, more generally, on loop iteration i, it takes on the value 3<sup>i</sup>.

Given that this loop stops as soon as k is greater than or equal to n, we can work out how many loop iterations there will be by solving for the smallest value of i for which 3<sup>i</sup> ≥ n. We can do that as follows:

> 3<sup>i</sup> = n
>
> i = log<sub>3</sub> n

This number might not be a whole number, so we'll round up by taking the ceiling and say that the number of iterations is **⌈log<sub>3</sub> n⌉**.

Generally speaking, if you see some process that works by repeatedly growing by a constant factor (always tripling, or always doubling, or always going up by a factor of 10, etc.) you should expect to see some kind of logarithmic term show up. That's one of the most common ways you see O(log n) show up.

Comment: Ah that is very clear now.  I actually noted the relationship of k = 3^p and didn't even realize that p represented the iterations haha.  Thank you for the clear and concise explanation!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your observation is a little wrong.

For different values of n, the values of k and p after the end of 6th line will be:-

```
n = 1 => k = 1 and p = 0.

n = 3 => k = 3 and p = 1.

n = 9 => k = 9 and p = 2.

n = 10 => k = 27 and p = 3.

n = 27 => k = 27 and p = 3.

n = 30 => k = 81 and p = 4.
```

Now, at the end of the 6th line,

```
if n == k
  then 3^p == n
otherwise,
  3^(p-1) < n < 3^p
```